# pict2e \Vector is “Undefined control sequence”

Tags: pdftex, diagrams

The [pict2e package documentation (dated 2020-09-30)](https://mirror.easyname.at/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/pict2e/pict2e.pdf) in chapter Extensions describes a new command `\Vector(hX1,Y1 i)(hX2,Y2 i)`. However, I get an error that the macro is not definded when I try this in

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pict2e}
\begin{document}
    \setlength\unitlength{1cm}
    \begin{picture}(10,10)(-5,-5)
        \put(0,0){\vector(2.5,2.9){2}}
        \put(0,0){\vector(2.5,2.8){2}}
        \Vector(1,2)(3,5)
    \end{picture}
\end{document}
```

Unrelated to the problem, I added two `\vector` invocations, too, in order to convince myself that the `pict2e` package is working at least for this overridden definition.

What am I doing wrong in my use of `\Vector`?

Comment: Your example works for me...

Comment: Your code works perfectly on the latest version of MikTeX. Update your LaTeX distribution!

Comment: No issues on TL2020 either. If you're using miktex remember to update in both miktex user mode and miktex admin mode (if you have both)